# Converting scss to css using gulp. [Problems]

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I have been trying to convert scss to css and this is my code.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
   return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
```

I get no errors but it just dosnt do anything.

```
[05:12:54] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/Project/gulpfile.js
[05:12:54] Starting 'sass'...
[05:12:54] Finished 'sass' after 13 ms
```

This is my scss file, not sure if thats useful to know.

```
.lol {
  width: percentage(100/2);
}
```

[Workspace.](https://gyazo.com/ad0464dcb6318bc41fc595df5ea50a01)
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a trailing slash in `gulp.dest('app/css')`, causing gulp to write to file named `css` in the `app` folder.

Instead, your `sass` task should read:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
   return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'));
});
```

Comment: That still doesn't seem to fix the problem. :(

Comment: There is a typo in your `scss` folder. You've spelt it as `sccs` instead ;)

Comment: That was the problem! so hard to spot as the author xD